# < table of extent 0 > when adding elements via loop R

Tags: r

ATL is a group of number 1,2,3,4 that I want to chart for various subjects

When I run the below, the output I get when I call up elements of ATLdata is:
"< table of extent 0 >"

```
ATLdata <- list()

for(subject in Subjects){
    ATL <- paste(subject, ".ATL.Y8.Data.Point.8.1", sep="")
    ATLdata[[subject]] <- table(df$ATL)
 }
```

However, when I add it outside a loop as below, it works fine

```
ATLdata$Technology <- table(df$Technology.ATL.Y8.Data.Point.8.1)
ATLdata$Technology
```

What do I need to do to be able to get this to work inside the loop?

Comment: What does `Subjects` look like? Preferably, share the output of `dput(Subjects)`.

Comment: Not `table(df$ATL)` This doesn't work. Use `table(df[[ATL]])`. Also `paste(subject, ".ATL.Y8.Data.Point.8.1", sep="")` could be `paste0(subject, ".ATL.Y8.Data.Point.8.1")`.